# .htaccess RewriteRule always overwritten - how to prevent?

Tags: htaccess

My Wordpress `.htaccess` file `RewriteRule` is always overwritten.

The text below is something suspicious to me. Please tell me how to decipher it. Thank you.

```
RewriteRule ^(plusquamperfect)\/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\/(.*)$ ?plusquamperfect$3=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}[L]
```

Comment: when WordPress update the htaccess file, it overwrites what is inside `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` then you need to add your rules outside of this block.

Comment: Do you recognise `plusquamperfect` as being part of your URL structure at all? Possibly related: [Stop WordPress and Plugins from Overwriting .htaccess](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/282285/stop-wordpress-and-plugins-from-overwriting-htaccess)

Comment: It would also be helpful to know _where_ this appears in your `.htaccess` file to be able to confirm whether it has any influence.